# Plot a CSV file where the delimiter is '; ' (semicolon + space)

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I'm learning how to plot things (CSV files) in Python, using `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`.

```
Column1;Column2;Column3;
1;4;6;
2;2;6;
3;3;8;
4;1;1;
5;4;2;
```

I can plot the one above with `plt.plotfile('test0.csv', (0, 1), delimiter=';')`, getting the figure below.

[image]

I can also plot that data if I change the separator from `';'` (semicolon) to `','` (comma).

```
Column1,Column2,Column3,
1,4,6,
2,2,6,
3,3,8,
4,1,1,
5,4,2,
```

using `plt.plotfile('test0.csv', (0, 1), delimiter=',')`.

But didn't managed to plot data where the separator is `'; '` (semicolon + space), as show below. Can I still shoot this with `matplotlib.pyplot` or it's time to something else?

```
Column1; Column2; Column3; 
1; 4; 6; 
2; 2; 6; 
3; 3; 8; 
4; 1; 1; 
5; 4; 2;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the error matplotlib is throwing you is

```
 TypeError: "delimiter" must be a 1-character string
```

Which makes it seem very unlikely you can use `'; '`. I also had errors thrown when I tried `delimiter=';'` although you may wish to check that that is reproducible.

However pandas handles this just fine with `pd.read_csv` if you have it available.

```
import pandas as pd
alpha = pd.read_csv(filepath,delimiter=';')
alpha.Column1
0    1
1    2
2    3
3    4
4    5
Name: Column1, dtype: int64
```

Comment: pandas wraps matplotlib's plotting functions, too.